# CodeMirror não exibe de primeira em uma modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins

Galera estou criando um modelo padrão para leitura de XML e para facilitar a vida dos usuários do sistema, estou exibindo um modelo default de exemplo em uma modal com o codemirror, entretanto, ele não exibe de primeira, o código só é exibido quando eu clico na área do codemirror.

[image: Modal de exibição do XML, ao clicar no centro o codemirror funciona]

Método js codemirror

```
//codemirror
var editor_two = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code2"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        mode: "xml",
        htmlMode: true,
    });
    //fim
```

Método modal

```
   //exibe modal de xml padrao
    $(".btnPadraoXml").on("click", function () {
       //exibe modal
       $("#myModalVisualizaModeloXMl").modal();             
        //tentativas sem sucesso
        editor_two.focus();
        //editor_two.on('shown');    

    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue código abaixo:

```
    //exibe modal de xml padrao
    $(".btnPadraoXml").on("click", function () {   
        $("#myModalVisualizaModeloXMl").modal();             
        //resolvido
        setTimeout(function() {            
            editor_two.refresh()
        }, 2000);
    })
```